# Monotone Convergence Theorem: Application for $p$-norms

Tags: measure-theory, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces, expectation

Let $X$ be a non-negative random variable in $L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{A},P)$.

We have shown that $$||\min(X,M)||_p \leq c$$ for all $M \geq 0$

and want to conclude that $$||X||_p \leq c.$$

In the lecture notes it is written that this follows by Monotonce Convergence theorem. But how does this work precisely?

So we have $$\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \min(X,M)=X$$

and therefore

$$||X||_p = ||\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \min(X,M)||_p=E[(\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \min(X,M))^p]^{1/p}=\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}E[\min(X,M)^p]^{1/p} =\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} ||\min(X,M)||_p \leq \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} c = c $$

Is this correct? Is it clear that I can pull out the limit even though it is inside $(\cdot)^p$?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Yes, it is correct. Here is the same argument with a little mor details:

Note that, $M \rightarrow \infty$, $\min(X,M)$ converge monotonically to $X$, so $\min(X,M)^p$ converge monotonically to $X^p$.  So we have: 

$$\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}E[\min(X,M)^p]=E[(\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} \min(X,M))^p] = E[X^p] = (||X||_p)^p$$
Thus 

$$||X||_p =(\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}E[\min(X,M)^p])^{1/p}= \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty}(E[\min(X,M)^p])^{1/p} = \\ =\lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} ||\min(X,M)||_p  \leq \lim_{M \rightarrow \infty} c = c $$